# Save Changes made in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**THE APP** : My e-commerce application has an activity to view and purchase products and add it to cart

*image for reference* :https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Ug58s6O8yQA/XFFJWIxU4YI/AAAAAAAAFYo/LmIxVFSZDHkWPI95WGBhf_5uVkKDbqnQQCLcBGAs/s640/Nexus%2B5x-Screenshot1.png

**PROBLEM** : I can add items just fine ... but once I open the next activity and get back to this activity , **all the quantity is set to its initial quantity in TextView as '0' again**

**WHAT I TRIED** : I surfed the internet to come across several solutions SavedInstances ,Shared preferences etc.. all of them only suit for not more than a couple of TextViews...since mine has unpredictable data from firebase database and contains number of textviews its quite impossible to store them in shared pref or arraylist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the Android documentation? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: @HenryTwist could you help me with the code with any of these methods?

Comment: What do you need help with specifically? The documentation should cover roughly everything you need to know.

Comment: @HenryTwist I understood i should cache it in local storage but could fnd how to do that in the documentation

Comment: Well it lists 5 different solutions, are none of those appropriate for your use case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem occurred because  mishandling view lifecycle you have to handle it try to save your changes in the dataset not only view

Comment: bro , the dataset is actually obtained from a remote database , how to save changes to that?

Comment: obtained from remote but you have your local copy save change on it i

Comment: your local data is refrence untill you call for newer version  @SriRam

Answer (score -2):

> "but once I open the next activity and get back to this activity , all
> the quantity is set to its initial quantity in TextView as '0' again"

Are you setting default values in `onResume()` of your `FirstActivity`?

Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) for more info on Activity Lifecycle.

Comment: How to use onResume()  to retain the values in all those textviews? not quite familiar with that